# how to display currency format in textview

Tags: android

I want to display the currency format in textview.
for example, if in the database is 2000
then it will be 2.000

here is that I've tried:

```
    public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ModelItems> arraylistitem;

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ItemsActivity main;

    public ItemAdapter(ItemsActivity main, List<ModelItems> itemsModel) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    public ItemAdapter(Context context,
                       ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist, List<ModelItems> populationlist) {
        this.context = context;
        this.main.itemsModel = populationlist;
        data = arraylist;
        this.arraylistitem = new ArrayList<ModelItems>();
        this.arraylistitem.addAll(populationlist);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return main.itemsModel.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    static class ViewHolderItem {
        TextView nameItem;
        TextView priceItem;
        ImageView imageItem;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolderItem holder = new ViewHolderItem();
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) main.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

            holder.nameItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            holder.priceItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_price);
            holder.imageItem = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgItem);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Locale locale = new Locale("id", "id");
        NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
        holder.priceItem.setText(fmt.format(this.main.itemsModel.get(position).getPrice()));
        holder.priceItem.setText(this.main.itemsModel.get(position).getPrice());
        holder.nameItem.setText(this.main.itemsModel.get(position).getName());
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

But it is still error.
Can you help me, since I am beginning in Android

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this for converting your text in $ currency

```
Locale locale = Locale.US;
NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
String currencyText = fmt.format(this.main.itemsModel.get(position).getPrice());
holder.priceItem.setText(currencyText);
```

The Locale class provides many Locale constants for different countries.

Go to this link if you want some other currency. You can look from static variables this class offers.

[Java Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html)

Comment: it's still not working,
here is the error `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.rki, PID: 14190
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad class: class java.lang.String at java.text.NumberFormat.format(NumberFormat.java:307) at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(DecimalFormat.java:705) at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:93)
at com.rki.adapter.ItemAdapter.getView(ItemAdapter.java:86)`

Comment: Please put breakpoints on these 3 statements and verify that the locale and NumberFormat object are initializing correctly

Comment: Also let me know the use case you are passing in the format function

Comment: @Allegra follow the official guide for [Debugging](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html)

Comment: I have edited my answer for your convenience. Please debug the code to let me know the exact line on which the app is crashing. This code is working on my end fine